# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not resolve all task dependencies

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

Please Help
This error appears in most photo editing applications , Knowing that the application was in the past working without problems, and the problem appeared after updates to Android Studio

**Error :**
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Could not resolve com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9.

```
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Skipped due to earlier error
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

// Gradle file //

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0.6"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'}}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false}}
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'


implementation 'org.wysaid:gpuimage-plus:2.6.3-min'


implementation 'com.hold1:keyboardheightprovider:0.0.9'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.steelkiwi:cropiwa:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.3'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.agrawalsuneet.androidlibs:dotsloader:1.4'
implementation 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.8'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
```

Gradle -

```
  buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()        
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android"
    }}}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

Comment: jcenter and bintray are down today. Both will disappear forever soon as well. Feb 2022?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.